# I am unable to launch Selenium using webdriver on Mac on InteliJ

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch a website/any website but its not working ,previously it worked but now all of a sudden I am getting an error .Please note dont be harsh I am new to coding and selenium I am self taught so if the answer is clear I apologize in advance.
    ====================================================================
    THIS IS MY CODE IN INTELLIJ
    package com.Selenium2020;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class PluralSelenium {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/admin/Documents/Selenium_Project_2020/src/chromedriver 4");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            driver.get("https://twitter.com/logout/error");
        enter code here

        }

}
==============================================
See error below ======

Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}) on port 30215
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'admins-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.177', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b41e99 chromedriver 4 + 3747481
1   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103ad64d3 chromedriver 4 + 3306707
2   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103865fef chromedriver 4 + 749551
3   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037c79db chromedriver 4 + 100827
4   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037c3ad1 chromedriver 4 + 84689
5   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037f1f97 chromedriver 4 + 274327
6   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037ef163 chromedriver 4 + 262499
7   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037c9b0d chromedriver 4 + 109325
8   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037caaa5 chromedriver 4 + 113317
9   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b04f7f chromedriver 4 + 3497855
10  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b11b7d chromedriver 4 + 3550077
11  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b11908 chromedriver 4 + 3549448
12  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103ae4029 chromedriver 4 + 3362857
13  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b123d8 chromedriver 4 + 3552216
14  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103af8a37 chromedriver 4 + 3447351
15  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b27f94 chromedriver 4 + 3641236
16  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b47c87 chromedriver 4 + 3771527
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff710742eb _pthread_body + 126
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff71077249 _pthread_start + 66
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7107340d thread_start + 13

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at com.Selenium2020.PluralSelenium.main(PluralSelenium.java:16)

Process finished with exit code 1Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}) on port 30215
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'admins-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.177', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b41e99 chromedriver 4 + 3747481
1   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103ad64d3 chromedriver 4 + 3306707
2   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103865fef chromedriver 4 + 749551
3   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037c79db chromedriver 4 + 100827
4   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037c3ad1 chromedriver 4 + 84689
5   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037f1f97 chromedriver 4 + 274327
6   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037ef163 chromedriver 4 + 262499
7   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037c9b0d chromedriver 4 + 109325
8   chromedriver 4                      0x00000001037caaa5 chromedriver 4 + 113317
9   chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b04f7f chromedriver 4 + 3497855
10  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b11b7d chromedriver 4 + 3550077
11  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b11908 chromedriver 4 + 3549448
12  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103ae4029 chromedriver 4 + 3362857
13  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b123d8 chromedriver 4 + 3552216
14  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103af8a37 chromedriver 4 + 3447351
15  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b27f94 chromedriver 4 + 3641236
16  chromedriver 4                      0x0000000103b47c87 chromedriver 4 + 3771527
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff710742eb _pthread_body + 126
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff71077249 _pthread_start + 66
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7107340d thread_start + 13

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at com.Selenium2020.PluralSelenium.main(PluralSelenium.java:16)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check which chrome version you are using and download chrome driver from the below link and set binary path accordingly. I think you are using old chrome driver

```
Your Error Message : ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78
```

[Download chrome driver from here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much - I see it now my chrome version was on version 80 so I downloaded the latest chrome driver and that sorted the error once again thank you